# Removing ID selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been teaching myself CSS through CodeSchool and came across a challenge whose answer doesn't make sense to me.

The directions are: "Refactor #home scoped anchor tags to be scoped to the .home class instead, so that the .button declaration no longer needs reference to the home class or ID." (Without changing anything in the HTML code.)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/codeschool-courses/1641690#file-2-5-html) is the HTML source and here is the CSS I was told to refactor:

```
#home a {
  color: #c09e79;
}
#home article .button {
  color: #fff;
}
```

With the correct answer being:

```
.home a {
  color: #c09e79;
}
article .button {
  color: #fff;
}
```

In the HTML the only reference to "home" was as an ID- why is it okay to change it, in the CSS, to a class without editing the HTML to read as "class='home'"?

Sorry if this is common knowledge, I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: The HTML does have a 'home' class...

Comment: I saw that but it didn't really hit me until it was pointed out, not sure how to explain but I thought it was something different since it was a string of words instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the section already has "home" as an ID *and* as a class:

```
<section id="home" class="content home group">
```

"home" is the second class. The section has three classes, separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<section id="home" class="content home group">
```

There are 3 classes defined:

```
content
home
group
```

You can define multiple classes to an attribute using spaces in between.